# GLKView rendering wrong resolution drawableHeight is wrong

Tags: ios, iphone, resolution, glkit, glkview

Im rendering with

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect

But the resolution its delivering is for an iPhone 5 and I'm rendering on an iPhone 6 the drawableHeight is calling out at 320 instead of 375

Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: Most likely the initialization is done too soon. So the width of the view is still 320. Then the buffer keeps the size. I would try to avoid the GLKView overall but you could try to do the following: In the view controller that has the view override awakeFromNib and in it call self.view.setNeedsLayout() and self.view.layoutIfNeeded(). This is quite an often issue in the latest SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out settings had changed in my iPhone storyboard